# Java & Python Type Checking

Tags: java, python, types

What really is the difference in the way that Java and Python implement type checking?

And what about how they implement abstract data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does.

Python does not.

Python is strongly dynamically typed. You create an object, and it will always be of that type. However, the variable that points to that object, can be pointed to any object of any type, and doesn't have to know what type of object it points at.

Edit based on questions in the comments:

This allows you to define a class that can be used by most functions that expect a dictionary, or a list, or another type, very easily. So If I want to create a special kind of list, that when you iterate over it, returns the objects in a custom order, all I have to do is declare a class that supports `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, and a few other methods, and other classes will use it just as if it were a list.

For information on abstract base classes in Python, see http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class. In use, they are quite similar to abstract base classes in Java.

Comment: so that would make Java a better huh? it seems like thats more room for error with python

Comment: It is a feature. It gives you more power. You can define a class that will act like a list, and can be used by any method that takes a list. You can make a class which acts like a file, and allows you to feed data to or catch data from code that expects a file object.

Comment: Wrong. Python do type checking at runtime, Java do type checking at compile time. In Python, names are untyped, but Python objects are strongly typed.

Comment: "Better" is in the eye of the beholder.  Like you, I think the lack of strong type checking leads to more errors -- or, it does when I write code.  (Maybe I need the compiler as a crutch.)  But I've met a lot of programmers who prefer something like Python or PHP that isn't strongly typed.

Comment: Python _is_ strongly typed, it's just not statically typed. PHP, however, is both weakly typed and dynamically typed.

Comment: @LieRyan Most times Python doesn't care about type, so long as the object supports the right actions, with special methods such as `__getattr__`, `__iter__`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Python, like Ruby, uses [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), which is a style of dynamic typing. Java obviously is statically typed, and type checking is done at compile time.